# How to organize default order in pagination?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, will-paginate

I use will_paginate with ajax sort and seen railscasts.com. 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

My collection for pagination

```
@cars = Car.joins(:engine).includes(:engine).select('cars.*, engines.*').order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

But when I went to the index page, I jumped out error.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Items#index
```

SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: name: SELECT  "cars"."id" AS t0_r0, "cars"."name" AS t0_r1, "cars"."model_id" AS t0_r2, "cars"."city_id" AS t0_r3, "cars"."created_at" AS t0_r4, "cars"."updated_at" AS t0_r5, "cars"."engine_id" AS t0_r6, "engines"."id" AS t1_r0, "engines"."name" AS t1_r1, "engines"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "engines"."updated_at" AS t1_r3 FROM "cars" INNER JOIN "engines" ON "engines"."id" = "cars"."engine_id" **ORDER BY name** asc LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0

But when I go to a page already sorted, it works for me.

I think mistake in default Order in SQL.

How to set 'cars.name' instead 'name'?

Comment: Please show the code where you set the default sort field. Where do you set `sort_column`?

Comment: I copied code from railscasts   http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

Comment: sort_column used in one place and I could not initially determine.

Comment: Sorry, but if you can't even find it in your own code, I cannot help you.

Comment: I understand that if I ask the original value as "cars.name", it will save the situation. But if I'm in the controller sets the value of sort_column ||= "cars.name", the sort is always so (by cars.name).

Answer (score 0):

I found method and set sort default

```
private



 def sort_column
    Car.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "cars.name"
  end
```